# Automatically Adding Current Timestamp on Row Insertion in GCP BigQuery

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, apache-beam

I am seeking advice regarding the insertion of rows in a Google Cloud Platform (GCP) BigQuery table. Specifically, I am interested in understanding if it is possible for BigQuery to automatically add the current timestamp into a dedicated column each time a new row is inserted.

I am aware that I can accomplish this by generating a timestamp from my Java code and including it in the data that I'm sending to BigQuery. However, I am curious to know if there's a way for BigQuery itself to handle this functionality, similar to the DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP feature available in some SQL-based relational databases.

Is there a built-in feature or SQL command in BigQuery that would allow me to do this, or would this functionality always need to be handled at the application level (in my case, Java)?

Comment: Just `mycol timestamp default current_timestamp`. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/default-values

Answer (score 1):

According to @GMB, you can use this line of query:

```
mycol timestamp default current_timestamp
```

Posting this answer as a Community Wiki since this is a possible workaround and for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future.